# Can't find Java JDK in IntelliJ, running Fedora 24

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fedora

I can't find the directory in which to set up Java as my project JDK in IntelliJ. I tried pointing it to /usr/java/java[version-number] but IntelliJ said that it was an invalid directory. (I don't remember exactly what the folder was called, I just remember it was Java 8.)

I did some googling and found out that it may be because it was corrupted, and they recommended wiping it and doing a reinstall... so I deleted the java[version-number] folder in /usr/java and attempted to do a reinstall by downloading the jdk rpm file from Oracle's website, but apparently I still have the 1.8.0 JDK installed?

When I type in `java -version` into terminal, I get the following:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_102"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)`

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Press ctrl + alt + shift + s (project settings), you should have jvm setup somewhere there.

Comment: Try `echo $JAVA_HOME` in a terminal. It should point you to where your Java is installed.

Comment: @Tobb I can't access project settings because I don't have an sdk set up...

Comment: @haffla nothing shows up

Comment: Newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA ships with a built-in jdk for running IDEA itself, so I take it that's not the problem? Opening project settings should not require that project jdk is set. But is it the IDEA jdk that is missing?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was different. I installed IntelliJ's flatpack version of the IDE.

flatpack has [restrictions](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html) to use the file system.

These directories are blacklisted:

```
/lib, /lib32, /lib64, /bin, /sbin, /usr, /boot, /root, /tmp, /etc, /app, /run, /proc, /sys, /dev, /var
```

Exceptions from the blacklist: `/run/media`

These directories are mounted under `/var/run/host: /etc, /usr`

So you have to use path something like /var/run/host/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.
I actually downloaded the IntelliJ Toolbox and installed it from there.

Answer (score 0):

try `whereis java` maybe it'll show up in your terminal